# Are PurcharseOrders supported in QBO Api?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Are PurchaseOrders supported in QuickBooks Online API (QBO) or only in QuickBooks Desktop (QBD) Api?  It does not seem be clear from Intuit's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported in QBO. But in QBD it is.

QBO - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/0500_supported_entities_and_operations

QBD - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0500_supported_objects

**Update**
In QBO V3 API(new), Purchase order is supported for QBO.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/0500_v3_supported_entities_and_operations

Thanks

Comment: Worth noting that the v3 API *is not available* for general use yet.